# Typical UITableViewCell with autolayout

Tags: ios, uitableview, interface-builder, autolayout

How do you layout the following `UITableViewCell` using Interface Builder and autolayout?
[image: Layout]

**Requirements**

- The *imageView* is vertically centered and has a fixed size.
- The *textLabel* and *detailTextLabel* have fixed vertical spacing between them.
- The *textLabel* and *detailTextLabel* together must be vertically centered in relation to the *imageView*.
- The height of the *textLabel* and *detailTextLabel* together must not be bigger than the height of the *imageView*.
- The *textLabel* and *detailTextLabel* can use more than one line if required. The *textLabel* has more priority than the *detailTextLabel*.

**Examples**

(not pixel-perfect)

[image: detailTextLabel two lines]
[image: textLabel two lines]

Comment: I managed to ignore Interface Builder and autolayout until iOS 7. Now I'm striving to use both because they're the future. Right? Right?

Comment: I love the question but I do worry that any answer would really need to be a long blog entry that not only gave code (probably can't be done in IB due to your #4 and #5 requirements needing program logic) but also explained the detail behind constraints (content hugging vs content compression). Also, implicit is a #6 requirement which would be `"works in both portrait and landscape"`.

Comment: I don't understand where all the love is coming from for this question (right now there is 4 up-votes). This question does not satisfy the following requirement: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results." So where's the attempted solutions?

Comment: @RoboticCat "It's not possible to do it in IB" is also a valid answer.  I'm not sure, though. There might a solution playing with priorities, content resistance and inequalities.

Comment: @bilobatum Actually, I'm not asking for code. Regarding attempted solutions, I felt all my experiments would confuse more than help. I usually add them, or post my own solution, after a little bit.

Comment: @bilobatum: I understand your point of view; the question doesn't strictly satisfy the StackOverflow requirements.  But for me, a solution (or a blog) that explained how to do this (including perhaps calculating a variable cell height) would go a very long way to removing many of the questions about autolayout I see constantly on StackOverflow.

Comment: some advice from a painful past: Try to avoid autolayout for UITableViewCells (and UICollectionViewCell etc.). Most likely performance will suck on everything that is not an iPhone 5s. Using [CGGeometry](http://nshipster.com/cggeometry/) to calculate the layouts will be much faster and hence lead to much better frame rates when scrolling.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch +1 Oh, I'm avoiding autolayout all right. I'm just trying to make a real effort to learn it.

Comment: don't get me wrong, Autolayout is awesome. I use it whenever possible. A couple of months ago I was in the "use Autolayout everywhere" phase myself. I spent days to layout all my cells with Autolayout. It finally looked beautiful, and everything resized automatically. Then I started to scroll the tableview. And the frame rate went down to 10 fps. So I reverted everything to my old ugly CGRect* methods, and the frame rate was back at 30 something. Though, this was on an old device and I basically changed constraints for every displayed cell. So your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

Not all these requirements together can be expressed using Auto Layout. If you want something that complex, you'll have to do manual layout implementing -layoutSubviews.

In this case, considering it's only 3 views it won't be a lot of code.